# why dividing a number by 1.25 gives back 20 percent less of original?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

So i had to takeout the discount from price.

```
price = 10
discount = 20%
```

my default method has been: `price - price*discount`

`10 - 10*.20 = 8`

but i had a hunch it should be possible to just do this by diving or multiplying.

So after tries i found that this works too, dont remember how i got to the number...

`10/1.25 = 8`

how does it work. how can i find other denominators for other percentages.

i feel this is stupidly simply question, but my brain is sort of not working so please help.

Comment: dividing by 1 gives 100%, 1.5 should give 85%, 2 gives 50%,

Comment: to get denominator `1/1-d = x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e$ is the expenditure, $p$ the price and $d$ the discount, you are using the relation:
$$
e=p(1-d)
$$
you want express $e=p/c$ , so you have:
$$
\dfrac{p}{c}=p(1-d)
$$
and you find:
$$
c=\dfrac {1}{1-d}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{10}{1.25} = \frac{10}{\frac{5}{4}} = \frac{4}{5} \times 10 = 0.8 \times 10 = 10(1-0.2) = 10 - (10\times0.2)$

Thus you have your original number minus $20\%$ of it